# How to exclude action activities from ShareSheet?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

I am using a ShareLink to share a file, in this case, a pdf. I want to exclude Activities like Messages in the same way I can do it with the ActivityController. How can I do it with ShareLink?

```
  ...
  let fileURL =  URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: path)
  ShareLink(item: fileURL){
     Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
  }
```

[image]